# Grouping parameters

Tags: haskell

Say I have functions which accept the same parameters and I want to test if their outputs are equivalent for the same input.

```
f :: a -> b -> c
g :: a -> b -> c
f a b == g a b
```

How can I package the parameters a and b in x so I can write the following instead.

```
f x == g x
```

What are the best ways to accomplish this without needing to wrap the functions themselves?

Comment: You can [`uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) the functions.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of the uncurry function. What I was interested in was if there was a way to achieve the same effect without having to wrap the function in an uncurry first.

Comment: That's really the only way to do it. Why don't you want to do it that way?

Comment: Neither `f` or `g` take more than one argument (*all* functions take exactly one argument); currying along with left-associative function application just provides the illusion of multi-argument functions. You can't package the parameters, you can only define new functions, which is what `uncurry` does.

Comment: @Joseph Sible I was curious.

Comment: @chepner that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do *exactly* what you’re asking is to use `uncurry`:

```
let
  x = (a, b)
in uncurry f x == uncurry g x
```

(Or `uncurryN` for `N` arguments.)

However, instead of packaging the arguments in a tuple, you could use the `(->) x` instance of `Applicative` (i.e., functions taking `x` as input) to implicitly “spread” the arguments to the parameters of both functions, so at least you only have to mention them once. This instance is commonly used in point-free code.

For example, using `liftA2` specialised to this instance:

```
-- General type:
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c

-- Specialised to ‘(->) x’ (using TypeApplications syntax):
liftA2 @((->) _) :: (a -> b -> c) -> (x -> a) -> (x -> b) -> (x -> c)
```

You get this pattern:

```
liftA2 h f g x
-- =
(h <$> f <*> g) x
-- =
h (f x) (g x)
```

To lift more arguments, you add another `liftA2` or `… <$> … <*> …`:

```
liftA2 (liftA2 h) f g x y
-- =
(liftA2 h <$> f <*> g) x y
-- =
h (f x y) (g x y)
```

So in a case like yours:

```
f, g :: Int -> Char -> Bool
f i c = chr i == c
g i c = i == ord c

(liftA2 . liftA2) (==) f g :: Int -> Char -> Bool
-- =
liftA2 (liftA2 (==)) f g
-- =
(\ x y -> f x y == g x y)
```

The `N` in `liftAN` corresponds to the number of *functions*; the number of `liftAN` calls corresponds to the number of arguments.